# Executing Unix shell scripts in talend open studio for big data

Tags: unix, scripting, talend

Is it possible to execute a shell script in talend, the same way we run scrips in informatica using command task?

I am new to talend. I have few scripts running in UNIX servers through informatica, Can i achieve the same using TALEND?

I have installed TALEND in windows server. Is it possible to install the same in unix server? (should it be installed to run unix scripts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can execute the shell scripts on your unix server using Talend Studio for Data Integration. The component to use is tSystem which can call shell scripts.

Check below help links for demo with tSystem component
https://help.talend.com/display/KB/Executing+a+command+with+spaces+using+a+tSystem+component
http://www.vikramtakkar.com/2013/04/tsystem-how-to-execute-unix-or-linux.html

There is no need of separate Unix installer. Just call the specific Unix file like "TOS_DI-linux-gtk-x86.sh" to launch the studio on Unix Machine. You can find this file in installation root.

Answer (score 4):

If your job talend is runnning in a local machine whatever the OS, and you want to execute a Linux command or invoke a shell script in a remote machine, then you need [tSSH](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforBigDataComponentsReferenceGuide521EN/19.3+tSSH) component.

If the Talend job and the script are in the same machine, or you want to execute a local command system then you can use [tSystem](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforBigDataComponentsReferenceGuide521EN/19.4+tSystem).

Answer (score 0):

I have given a sample screenshot for the job implementation. tSSH has a option to call python/shell scripts

[image]